# Dieudonné's two functions being "tangent at a point"

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$, $F$ be two real Banach spaces and $A \subseteq E$ open. Dieudonné, "Treatise on analysis" chap. 8.1, defines two functions f, g to be *tangent at a point* $x_0 \in A$, if

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0, x \neq x_o} \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x-x_0|} = 0 ,$$

where $|\cdot|$ signifies respective norms on $E$ and $F$. What I can't find out is, whether this condition is equivalent to

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0, x \neq x_o} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{|x-x_0|} = \mathit{0} .$$

It seems clear to me that $|f(x)-g(x)| \rightarrow 0 $ is equivalent to $ f(x)-g(x) \rightarrow \mathit{0} $. But is the numerator in my claim still $o(|x-x_0|)$ in each component? How to prove that? Is there possibly a limitation on the kind of the norms or the Banach spaces in order for my claim to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both assertions mean that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x-x_0|}<\varepsilon.$$So, yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot (I should have known that)!